# Microsoft Bot Framework - giving blank spaces

Tags: node.js, botframework

How to give a blank space after writing some text in `session.send();`

For example,

```
session.send('Low    : 1<br/><br/>Medium : 2<br/><br/>High   : 3<br/><br/>Urgent : 4');
```

Should give output as

```
Low    : 1

Medium : 2

High   : 3 

Urgent : 4
```

[Link 1](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1112) I've gone through this, but it's relevant for what I am searching for

Here's the code and the screenshot

```
(session, args) => {

        session.dialogData.Email = args.response;

        builder.Prompts.text(session, "Set Priority");

        const msgText = `Low    : 1\n\nMedium : 2\n\nHigh   : 3\n\nUrgent : 4`;
        const msg = new builder.Message(session).text(msgText).textFormat('markdown');
        session.send(msg);
```

[image]
        },

Comment: For which channel are you trying to add blank lines?

Comment: Just want to show static output in bot interface with some spaces so it looks well managed. I've also tried `\n\n` but I think it is used for getting next line.

Comment: Can you give detail what kind of user experience are you going for? Can `Prompts.choice` work for you? https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/interfaces/_botbuilder_d_.__global.iprompts.html#choice

Comment: Basically, I have used this to set priority which will be done using `API call`. Using `Prompts.choice` is good idea but in this case it will make it more complex. I just want to give few blank spaces. Can't that be done by using `Session.send` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the channel you can use **Markdown** syntax. Here is an example.

```
const msgText = `Low &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;: 1
Medium : 2
High &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : 3
Urgent &nbsp; : 4`;
const msg = new BotBuilder.Message(session)
.text(msgText)
.textFormat("markdown");
session.send(msg);
```

For Markdown support check the channel inspector [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/WebChat?f=Markdown&e=example1). Actually with markdown you can do more.

<strike>**I have updated the code to use pre tags. Does that help?**</strike>

Updated once again. Following is the output:

[image]

===================

Although I think the functionality you are trying to achieve can be better achieved by utilizing BotBuilder Prompts library. Here is a sample:

```
bot.dialog("/", [
  function(session) {
    BotBuilder.Prompts.choice(
      session,
      "Select your option: ",
      ["Low", "Medium", "High", "Urgent"],
      { listStyle: BotBuilder.ListStyle.button }
    );
  },
  function(session, result: any) {
    session.send(
      `You selected ${result.response.index}: ${result.response.entity}`
    );
    session.endDialog();
  }
]);
```

Utilizing BotBuilder.Prompts library will also help in validation as the validation for selected option is built into the library, and if user has entered something giberish, the library auto-prompts by itself. Output:

[image]

Comment: Ok, I've tried above code and also visited the link. But I am not getting the expected output.
The channel used would be `Web Chat` but that deploying part will be in future.

So, suppose If I add the code for `Web Chat` and later if I deploy this on website will be shown properly ? (Because now in Bot interface it is not showing expected output )

Comment: Where are looking? Can you show the screenshot? Bot emulator & Test Channel in Azure portal both are based on WebChat, so if you are not getting the right results there, it is unlikely that you will get the right results after deployment. Can you post of the piece of code which you are using to send the message?

Comment: Even update answer is not working. I have also tried 
`
 const msgText = "<pre>Low    : 1\n\nMedium : 2\n\nHigh   : 3\n\nUrgent : 4</pre>";
  const msg = new builder.Message(session).text(msgText).textFormat('markdown');
  session.send(msg);
        `

Comment: Thankyou @MasterChief, both of them are working fine and I have managed to go with second method. (Could you give me your contact details. want to ask something in person) thankyou

Comment: If the answer worked for you, can you mark it as answer!